# Python issue with replace statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace

I've been write this practice program for while now, the whole purpose of the code is to get user input and generate passwords, everything almost works, but the replace statements are driving me nuts. Maybe one of you smart programmers can help me, because I'm kinda new to this whole field of programming. The issue is that replace statement only seems to work with the first char in Strng, but not the others one. The other funcs blower the last run first and then the middle one runs.

```
        def Manip(Strng):
          #Strng = 'jayjay'
          print (Strng.replace('j','h',1))
          #Displays: 'hayjay'
          print (Strng.replace('j','h',4))
          #Displays: 'hayhay'
          return



        def Add_nums(Strng):
            Size=len(str(Strng))
            Total_per = str(Strng).count('%')

            # Get The % Spots Position, So they only get replaced with numbers during permutation
            currnt_Pos = 0
            per = [] # % position per for percent
            rGen = ''
            for i in str(Strng):
                if i == str('%'):
                    per.append(currnt_Pos)
                currnt_Pos+=1
            for num,pos in zip(str(self.ints),per):
                rGen = Strng.replace(str(Strng[pos]),str(num),4);

            return rGen                 






        for pos in AlphaB: # DataBase Of The Positions Of Alphabets
            for letter in self.alphas: #letters in The User Inputs
                GenPass=(self.forms.replace(self.forms[pos],letter,int(pos)))
                # Not Fully Formatted yet; you got something like Cat%%%, so you can use another function to change % to nums 
                # And use the permutations function to generate other passwrds and then
                # continue to the rest of this for loop which will generate something like cat222 or cat333

                Add_nums(GenPass) # The Function That will add numbers to the Cat%%%
                print (rGen);exit()
```

Comment: Have you tried to read the documentation on the replace function?

Comment: Skimmed through it

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace

Comment: Which part of "If the optional argument count is given, only the first count occurrences are replaced" did you not understand?

Comment: and what do you wish to return from the function?

Comment: oh, I didn't read that, so that's why my code sucks, is there a alternative to replace

Comment: If the input is `jayjay`, what do you want the output to be?

Comment: so the user inputs the formatted string example f@x%%   @=alpha's %=nums  so then the user enter the numbs and alphas to use to generate with then the computer generate something like fox%% and it goes into to this function and then fox%% will have different such as fox456 and then I use itertool permutation to change around, but it seems like it always displaying as fox444 or fox555 etc.

Comment: Can you please show a [mcve] of the problem?

Comment: Okay, I'll add it to the code

Comment: Alright I post it a snippet of it